# Cannot solve mod_wsgi exception in Flask setup

Tags: python, apache, flask, mod-wsgi

I want to deploy a Flask app using Python 3. I am running Ubuntu 16.04, Apache2.

I ran sudo apt-get install libapache2-mod-wsgi-py3 to install wsgi.

I followed the instruction [here](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-deploy-a-flask-application-on-an-ubuntu-vps). I have a Flask App on my Linode server at /var/www/html/hxueh.net/finance. Inside the *finance* folder there is one file and one folder. The structure looks like this.

```
|--------finance
|----------------finance
|-----------------------static
|-----------------------templates
|-----------------------venv
|-----------------------application.py
|----------------finance.wsgi
```

In venv/bin:

```
activate activate_this.py flask pip3.5 python3.5
activate.csh easy_install pip python python-config
activate.fish easy_install-3.5 pip3 python3 wheel
```

The finance.wsgi is:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
import sys
import logging
logging.basicConfig(stream=sys.stderr)
sys.path.insert(0,"/var/www/html/hxueh.net/finance/")

from finance import app as application
```

And my Apache2 config is:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName finance.hxueh.net
        ServerAdmin hxueh1996@gmail.com
        WSGIScriptAlias / /var/www/html/hxueh.net/finance/finance.wsgi
        <Directory /var/www/html/hxueh.net/finance/finance/>
                Order allow,deny
                Allow from all
        </Directory>
        <Directory /var/www/html/hxueh.net/finance>
                WSGIProcessGroup finance
                WSGIApplicationGroup %{GLOBAL}
                Order deny,allow
                Allow from all
        </Directory>
        Alias /static /var/www/html/hxueh.net/finance/finance/static
        <Directory /var/www/html/hxueh.net/finance/finance/static/>
                Order allow,deny
                Allow from all
        </Directory>
        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        LogLevel warn
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

I have a Wordpress app running on the same server, with Certbot enabling Let's encrypt certificate.

When I visit my server it return Error 500. In error.log it shows:

```
[Sun Jan 21 10:40:56.310304 2018] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 26281] AH00169: caught SIGTERM, shutting down
[Sun Jan 21 10:41:21.236671 2018] [ssl:warn] [pid 26747] AH01909: hxueh.net:443:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
[Sun Jan 21 10:41:21.276195 2018] [ssl:warn] [pid 26748] AH01909: hxueh.net:443:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
[Sun Jan 21 10:41:21.276370 2018] [wsgi:warn] [pid 26748] mod_wsgi: Compiled for Python/3.5.1+.
[Sun Jan 21 10:41:21.276378 2018] [wsgi:warn] [pid 26748] mod_wsgi: Runtime using Python/3.5.2.
[Sun Jan 21 10:41:21.278888 2018] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 26748] AH00163: Apache/2.4.18 (Ubuntu) OpenSSL/1.0.2g mod_wsgi/4.3.0 Python/3.5.2 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Sun Jan 21 10:41:21.278910 2018] [core:notice] [pid 26748] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'
[Sun Jan 21 10:44:02.826408 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 26751] [client xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:xxx] No WSGI daemon process called 'finance' has been configured: /var/www/html/hxueh.net/finance/finance.wsgi
```

---

**UPDATE: Problem Solved.**

I rewrite the structure and put wsgi file inside the project.

```
|--------Finance
|----------------static
|----------------templates
|----------------venv
|----------------application.py
|----------------finance.wsgi
```

Also I rewrite the Apache 2 file. I disable WSGIProcessGroup since I don't need it.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName finance.hxueh.net
        ServerAdmin hxueh1996@gmail.com
        WSGIScriptAlias / /var/www/html/hxueh.net/Finance/finance.wsgi
        <Directory /var/www/html/hxueh.net/Finance/>
                Order allow,deny
                Allow from all
        </Directory>
        <Directory /var/www/html/hxueh.net/Finance>
                Order deny,allow
                Allow from all
        </Directory>
        Alias /static /var/www/html/hxueh.net/Finance/static
        <Directory /var/www/html/hxueh.net/Finance/static/>
                Order allow,deny
                Allow from all
        </Directory>
        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        LogLevel warn
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

Make sure to enable mod_wsgi in /etc/apache2/mods-available/mod.load. Just run `mod_wsgi-express module-config` and put the output inside. Then run `sudo a2enmod wsgi` and `sudo service apache2 restart`.

My finance.wsgi is:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
import sys
import logging
logging.basicConfig(stream=sys.stderr)
sys.path.insert(0,"/var/www/html/hxueh.net/Finance/")

from application import app as application
```

Finally, thanks Graham Dumpleton for helping me to deploying my first web app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have:

```
WSGIProcessGroup finance
```

to tell mod_wsgi to send requests to WSGI application running in a daemon process group but haven't configured the daemon process group.

Add before the `WSGIScriptAlias` directive:

```
WSGIDaemonProcess finance
```

Also read:

- http://modwsgi.readthedocs.io/en/develop/user-guides/configuration-guidelines.html#defining-process-groups

to learn more about daemon process groups.

BTW, version of mod_wsgi 4.3.0 is very old. You should avoid using system provided packages for mod_wsgi on Debian/Ubuntu as they are usually hopelessly out of date and are also unsupported. Suggest you uninstall the system package and install from source code yourself using `pip` install method. See:

- https://pypi.python.org/pypi/mod_wsgi

Comment: And did you look at the systemd logs for Apache service startup as the error messages told you to? Did you run ``mod_wsgi-express module-config`` to get the configuration you then needed to add into the Apache configuration so mod_wsgi was loaded?

Comment: I did run `mod_wsgi-express install-module`. I put `WSGIPythonHome "/usr"` before WSGIDaemonProcess and WSGIScriptAlias. It still doesn't work.

Comment: The ``WSGIPythonHome`` cannot be inside of a ``VirtualHost`` and if the value was ``/usr`` isn't actually needed as that is the system Python location anyway so should be found automatically. Where did you put the ``LoadModule`` line?

Comment: I put it at the very top of the file `LoadModule wsgi_module "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/mod_wsgi/server/mod_wsgi-py35.cpython-35m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so"`. It still doesn't work

Comment: WSGIPythonHome isn't necessary? When I run `python` it run Python 2 but my project is based on Python 3. Is that needed some tweak?

Comment: I think I made some mistake and I solve it. I should put `LoadModule` into `mods-available/wsgi.load`. But it also failed. I have some update in the question.

Comment: Have you used the ``journalctl -xe`` command at all? You want to run whatever systemd comand it is to view the startup logs. Looking at status tree doesn't tell you what error messages were logged on startup.

Comment: Hey, Graham, I have solved the problem. Thanks for your kindly helping.